# A ghci session without Prelude

Tags: haskell, ghci

This question arose on #haskell irc chat:

> How can I start ghci without importing prelude?

The possible answer seemed obvious:

> `ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude`, or load a file with `import Prelude ()`

The latter seems to work, while the former strangely does not. However, `import Prelude ()` imports the declared instances from Prelude, right? Is there a better way of creating a ghci session without loading Prelude at all?

Comment: `ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude` works perfectly, just not for what you thought it was for: it doesn't implicitly load the Prelude when interpreting files. =)

Comment: You can also do `import Prelude ()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore. This does work in ghci 8.0.2.

```
Prelude> :set -XNoImplicitPrelude
Prelude> :m -Prelude
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I confirmed this with ghc 8.2.1 as well.

Answer (score 17):

```
% ghci                    
GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m -Prelude 
> :i map

Top level: Not in scope: `map'
> :i Eq

Top level: Not in scope: data constructor `Eq'
```

However, I'm not sure about the *instances* and how ghci deals with them.

Is there a particular instance that you're concerned about?

Comment: "Is there a particular instance that you're concerned about?" Not really. Just concerned in general. I would imagine that `:m -Prelude` kills the instances, though.

Comment: I'm not sure the instances particularly matter, though, as the relevant classes would also be killed, so there'd be no way to get at them.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: yes (and I find it strange), but now `-XNoImplicitPrelude` seems to work as Dan expected (at least in GHC 7.6)